# What values can be assign to "X-Nginx-Cache" in .htaccess file

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, nginx, http-headers

I was making modifications to the `.htaccess` file on my website,
And I came across the `X-Nginx-Cache` directive, I am now using wordpress
So the directive was as follows

```
Header set X-nginx-cache "wordpress"
```

I know what `X-nginx` does and what's the point of it

**But :**

- What does the value `"wordpress"` mean?
- Is it the name of the cache container?
- Can the value be changed to any other name?
- If the name is changed, will some of the WordPress cache functions stop?
- Is there any relationship between the WordPress system itself and this value, or is it something related to the server only?

I searched a lot for the purpose of the name, but I did not find any satisfactory answer!!!

I appreciate everyone answering

I tried this directive in this way:

```
Header set X-nginx-cache "MyWebsiteName"
```

Or even this way:

```
Header set X-nginx-cache "ABCDEFGHIJK"
```

I did not notice any change, I browse the site normally, and I did not notice anything.

Comment: "I am now using wordpress So the directive was as follows" - What was it set to before? "I know what X-nginx does and what's the point of it" - What do you think it does and what do you think the point of it is?

Comment: @MrWhite "What do you think it does?" - A content cache sits in between a client and an “origin server”, and saves copies of all the content it sees،
My question is about the name, what does the name mean to nginx, you are asking me instead of giving a useful answer